# Regex: Match Optional URI Parameters

Tags: php, regex

Take a given URI, like this:

```
one/two/three
```

How would I match each character, in a capture group, between the slashes? This can be done with this method:

```
(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)
```

This gives me three groups where:

```
$1 = one
$2 = two
$3 = three
```

What I am having trouble with is making a capture group optional. I thought that this would work, thinking I could make each group optional (match zero or more):

```
(.+)?\/(.+)?\/(.+)?
```

Is there a way, using Regex or PHP to optionally match parts `one`, `two` or `three` of the above URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex

`^(?:(.+?))?(?:\/(.+?))?(?:\/(.+?))?$`

This will make all groups optional. The main point is using non-capturing groups with `?` quantifier, and `.+?` patterns to capture each part into separate group, so that you could reference them later with `$n`.

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/fL3aG0/2).

Sample code:

```
$re = "/^(?:(.+?))?(?:\\/(.+?))?(?:\\/(.+?))?$/m"; 
$str = "one/two/three\none/two\none\n\n"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: This matches parts one, two or three optionally, however I wanted each matched part (one, two or three) inside a capture group so I can reference them using $1, $2, or $3. Is this possible?

Comment: Ok, I think I will just make answer a bit shorter. :). All you need is to use non-greedy quanifiers (with `.+?`).